# Is there a font mapping database?

Tags: database, fonts, gdi+, psd

I'm looking for a statically generated, many-to-many, table of font names.

I'm parsing font names from .PSD files, which are created on both OS X and Windows computers.

I need to translate these font names into their closest counterparts on Windows GDI+.

A few example conversions I would need:

```
TimesNewRomanPSMT -> Times New Roman
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT -> Times New Roman, Bold
TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT -> Times New Roman, Bold, Italic
```

Adobe has a [1997 table](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5090.FontNameList.pdf) for Adobe fonts, but it's incorrect for anything past Win95.

Ghostscript has a table of font names, but it only covers about a dozen windows mappings.

Is this kind of database available anywhere?

Introspective analysis of the windows fonts would provide a **partial** table, but it would also be far too slow - this PSD parsing and re-rendering is happening in an HTTP request. I could statically generate it, bit it would add administrative overhead since it's too long to run at app startup, and would need to be done manually.

I was hoping that this kind of mapping table has already been created collaboratively somewhere.

This is for the [PsdComposer plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/psdcomposer) on http://imageresizing.net/